# Can you help me identify the error on this QuickSort algorithm? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, quicksort

I'm not able to identify the error on this code.

I can get it to sort everything, but the output is incomplete.

I don't know where the error is and why it is hiding part of the array.

I'm trying to do a quicksort code, I found this algorithm online and I'm trying to adapt to what I learn from InjectionSort, but it is not working.

The result should be:

```
Sorted array [
  { title: 'CSS', price: 10 },
  { title: 'PHP', price: 15 },
  { title: 'Python', price: 20 },
  { title: 'JavaScript', price: 25 },
  { title: 'Java', price: 30 },
  { title: 'Go', price: 45 },
  { title: 'Elixir', price: 50 }
]
```

But I'm getting:

```
Sorted array [
  { title: 'CSS', price: 10 },
  15,
  { title: 'Python', price: 20 },
  25,
  30,
  { title: 'Go', price: 45 },
  50
]
```

Here is the code:

```
function quicksort(array) {
  if (array.length <= 1) {
    return array;
  }

  var pivot = array[0].price;
  
  var left = []; 
  var right = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].price < pivot ? left.push(array[i]) : right.push(array[i]);
  }

  return quicksort(left).concat(pivot, quicksort(right));
};

var unsorted = [{
  title: "JavaScript",
  price: 25
},
{
  title: "PHP",
  price: 15
},
{
  title: "Java",
  price: 30
},
{
  title: "Elixir",
  price: 50
},
{
  title: "Go",
  price: 45
},
{
  title: "Python",
  price: 20
},
{
  title: "CSS",
  price: 10
},
];
var sorted = quicksort(unsorted);

console.log('Sorted array', sorted);
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you return the same array if its length is 0 or 1, but a new array (via [`concat`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)) if it’s longer; this inconsistency leads to either the same reference or a different reference being returned, which might lead to further bugs. Please return `array.slice();` in the first `if` statement.

Comment: `return quicksort(left).concat(pivot, quicksort(right));` notice `pivot` is not an array, is just the `price` value

Comment: try this: `return quicksort(left).concat(array[0], quicksort(right));`

Comment: Yes, it should be `const pivot = array[0];`, and the comparison should be against `pivot.price`.

Answer (score 1):

As [graficode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5334486/graficode) motioned in his comment, As per your code `pivot` is storing a price value instead of a whole object. Hence, while concatenating it is concatenating as a number instead of whole object. your pivot should be `pivot = array[0]` and it will resolve the issue.

Also Just a workaround, As Quick sort is a comparison sort and as per my understanding you want to sort the unsorted array of objects based on the `price` key. If Yes, you can do that with a JavaScript provided `sort` method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let unsorted = [{
  title: "JavaScript",
  price: 25
}, {
  title: "PHP",
  price: 15
}, {
  title: "Java",
  price: 30
}, {
  title: "Elixir",
  price: 50
}, {
  title: "Go",
  price: 45
}, {
  title: "Python",
  price: 20
}, {
  title: "CSS",
  price: 10
}];

unsorted.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);

console.log(unsorted)
```